# What is the proper way to accept multiple arguments in a custom attribute

Tags: c#, code-analysis, custom-attributes, parameters

I work with .NET 4.5 in VS2012 in an MVC4 web application. I am trying to build a custom attribute that accepts a yet unknown number of arguments.

I have the following code:

```
    public sealed class MyCustomAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly string[] _someStrings;       

        public MyCustomAttribute(params string[] someStrings)
        {
            _someStrings = someStrings;
        }
    }
```

and naturally I get the following code analysis warning:

> CA1019    Define accessors for attribute arguments    Add a public read-only
>   property accessor for positional argument 'someStrings' of
>   Attribute
>   'MyCustomAttribute'.

If I define an auto property with private set, I get the warning that I should return collections instead of an array

> CA1819    Properties should not return arrays Change
>   'MyCustomAttribute.SomeStrings' to return a
>   collection or make it a
>   method.

The problem is that I do not want to expose an array, since I do not want anyone to change what's inside the array. At most, I'd like to return a ReadOnlyCollection. If I change the type of the property to 'ReadOnlyCollection', I get the first warning again since it matches the property on name of the argument (case insensitive) and the type.

**Question:** How can I achieve this, without the need to suppress warnings?

Comment: I know you say you don't want anyone to change what's inside the array, but, attributes work a bit differently.  Why not just make the property public so you can specify the values when you use the attribute?  Once you specify the attribute, the code inside the class or method can't touch the attribute.

Comment: I can now use the argument by declaring [MyCustom("lba", "bla")]
If I make the array public (which would still give me the second warning in my question) I could edit the array via reflection.

Comment: I don't rly get why you are refering to reflection when talking about a public property... Even a private/internal property can be called with reflection. According to the MS guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56.aspx an attribute nees both a field (which is set using the constructor) and a public readonly property. Returning an array is never a good idea, since its very mutable. Which data are u sending into the attribute's constructor? But if you realy need an array I don't see the problem in surpressing the warning.

Comment: it's a variable number of arguments (refer to the code) and this is an implicit array. I think you have a point about reflection.
A colleague suggested to return an IEnumerable, I'm going to try that on monday.
Thx for all the suggestions so far!

Answer (score 1):

This is an API usability rule, and you're free to simply suppress the warning if there's no reason to expose the value via a property.  If you do want to expose the value, a property of type ReadOnlyCollection would amply fulfill the intent of the rule, even if the rule code doesn't recognize it.

Comment: So according to you, there is no way? (not to sound rude but this doesn't really answer my question :p )

Comment: There is no way to satisfy the screening code of both CA1019 and CA1819 without a suppression.  However, the way the CA1019 rule is coded is pretty "dumb" compared to its intent.  The intent of the rule is to make the contents of the positional argument(s) discoverable from outside the attribute at runtime, if this is appropriate.  A ReadOnlyCollection would satisfy the intent, but you will need a suppression since the rule code doesn't magically know this.